# Long running spark streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I have long-running spark streaming application (yarn client mode, EMR) that consumes data from Kafka. I can see that after a while application stops working because of 'out of space' problem (/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers is full)

Who can help with this issue?

Comment: The logs from your app or Spark logs are probably filling up all the space.  Either clean the logs or change the error levels to something more severe than INFO so that less logs are produced

Answer (score 0):

By default yarn aggregates logs into hdfs for completed jobs only.
However if you have a long running job on production you should configure log aggregation for running jobs too.

You achieve this by setting an appropriate for this property in yarn-site.xml

> yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Also make sure to set your log level to warn when on production.